# Beginner or intermediate skis for a first pair to buy?

Tags: skiing

I have only skied couple times and with the lesson plan I am getting ski pass next weekend!

I obviously don't want to rent Ski equipment all the time so I am looking to own one.

After doing some research, I don't feel like getting completely beginner skis as most likely I will have to upgrade next year.

Eventually, I feel like I might want to do little bit of everything and Salomon BBR 10.0 really caught my eyes. I was thinking of Salomon BBR 8.9 first, but 10.0 seems just better than 8.9.

I know I might have to struggle first couple times as I am only beginner and this skis is made for intermediate - advanced skiers.

What do you guys think? Any suggestions and recommendations will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Don't get intermediate to advanced skis if you're a beginner. I wouldn't even recommend getting new skis, get some used ones. If you're a beginner then you want shorter and softer skis, It makes a big difference.

Comment: Finding a good ski for you is like finding good shoes - 'fit' is the most important thing. As a life-long skier that sometimes puts on rented skis, I am sometimes shocked at how badly some 'intermediate' skis, even from good manufacturers, will actually feel. So I agree with ShemSeger - DON'T BUY. Also, don't rely too much on product description or reviews. Demo/borrow/or buy used, whatever you can to find out what works for you. Then you won't be (financially) committed to a bad ski. Repeat as you get better. Save your money good boots!

Comment: This question is close to what we call a "shopping question". Such are normally closed because they tend to get outdated rather quickly. However, in your case it looks quite easy to rephrase it such that it doesn't refer to a special product any more but asks the more general question what type of ski to buy in your situation. Maybe you might want to edit it that way?

Comment: I've edited the title to make it a little more generic.

Comment: Do a season long rental. That way you can turn in your beginner skis at the end of the year, and avoid the hassle of renting each time you're at the mountain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys! See my comment below for nhinkle for what I ended with! 

I will update once I try them next weekend!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very personal, subjective thing, and I don't think anybody can tell you exactly what type or even style of ski to get when you're first starting out. The perfect ski depends on how much you weigh, how that mass is distributed, what types of conditions you typically ski in, whether you ski on groomed paths or narrow trails, and many other considerations. For that reason, the advice I would give you is, *don't* buy your skis right away, and *do* rent some so you can get a feel for what works best for you. To make a brief analogy, I wouldn't rush out to buy a fancy road bike if I wasn't sure yet if I'd rather go mountain biking or road biking a lot.

Renting skis gives you the opportunity to try many different styles and sizes without having to make a long-term investment. You might inquire with local shops as to whether they have any discount program for repeated rentals. After you determine what kind of skis you really like, then you can start considering buying some.

Another thing to check out are ski swaps and discounted gear sales. You don't necessarily *need* brand-new skis to start out with; in fact, many experienced skiers primarily buy used gear. You could easily get 2 pairs of used skis for the same price as 1 pair of new skis, and having two different types of skis will give you more flexibility for different snow conditions and types of ski routes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment nhinkle! 

I really appreciate your input. I do agree with pretty much everything you have said. I did found a really good deal on mint condition Salomon 10.0 which was only used for day and already bought one. 

I also bought couple days used Black Diamond Factor 130 hybrid boots which could be used for both AT and lift downhill. 

I know both are bit of overkill, but that's what my guts tell me :) Eventually I wanna get into light backcountry skiing shortly and can't afford to buy whole new set of equipment for that so I took a risk!

Comment: I will let you guys know how I do with the intermediate/advanced skis and boots as beginner. Worst case, I could always possibly sell them for more as I got really good deal on both of them.

Comment: Those boots will hold you back. The big mistake most beginners make is to get boots that are too stiff for their skills. You have to be able to flex at the ankles to ski. A 130 flex boot is too much boot for a lot of advanced skiers, never mind a beginner.

Comment: I think the actual flex is only around 120. If I couldn't manage it, I will get a beginner one :) Thanks for the input!

Comment: bd factor 130 is really soft.  if you weigh >= 180 lbs and are athletically built it should be ok.  its also possible to adjust the cuff angle on that boot.  you can find a user manual for the boot online to explain this process.  adjusting the cuff angle may make it easier to engage the ski by making the boot more responsive to forward pressure.

Comment: I agree with this - however do buy boots. Well-fitting boots make a lot of difference to your enjoyment and ability (more so than skis at this level), and ownership frees you from hours sitting in a rental shop trying to find a pair that really fits you.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I am 5'11" and weigh 164 lbs, but I am still hoping BD Factor will turn out okay. Will update once I try this Saturday.